# how to get element has style attribute(padding present ) in a table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to find td element has padding style present in a table

i have tried to find td element has padding style attribute present in a table

$(Table).find('td[style="padding:*"]')
or
$(Table).find('td[style]')[1].css({"padding": "*"})

how to set new padding value for the td element

Comment: nearly there, use `[style*="padding"]` to check if it has that property no matter where it is within that attribute.

Comment: thq but how to set new padding value for the td element

Comment: `$(element).css('padding': '0')`

Comment: is this possible to do like this?
$(Table).find('td[style*="padding"]')[0].css('padding':'2pt')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked about jquery, but you can do this without it.

```
// Find all the elements with style tags with 'padding'.
const styled = document.querySelectorAll("td[style*='padding']");
```

More info about [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
// Now you can loop over the nodes you found, and set different styles.
styled.forEach(s => s.style.setProperty("padding-top", "2.5em"));

// html
// here's the html I tested the above code on
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: solid 1px;">Message</td>
      <td style="border: solid 1px;">Target</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 5px; border: solid 1px;">Hello</td>
      <td style="border: solid 1px;">World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```